# CSS Horizontal drop down adjusting borders

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, border

I would like a border around my drop down menu on hover. I want the right and left borders on the top menu to align with the border on the drop down. And I don't want to see the border underneath the text on the top menu. I'm not sure that I'm explaining things clearly so I'm including a [picture](http://i48.tinypic.com/lz1c7.jpg) of what I want.

[Here](http://cssdesk.com/YHtNd) is my attempt

Comment: One note: It does not always stay open for me. Perhaps you need to move to up a bit more? Otherwise a very good attempt indeed. Definately worth an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

That's a cool style.  To implement it, the CSS will need to do the following:

The tabs (#nav ul li a) will need a white background and a black border on the top, left, and right.

The dropdown will need a white background and a black border on all sides.

The trick is to use `z-index` to place the tab above the dropdown, and to make the tab slightly taller on hover.  The bottom of the tab should extend below the bottom of the tab row, in order to cover up part of the dropdown's top border.  Does that make sense?

If you'd like help with writing the CSS, I recommend adding code to your question.

Hope this helps!